# nginx load balance - magento 2

Tags: magento2, performance

I am trying to set nginx load balance I have planned like **Load Balance Nginx + Two Magento Instance + one database**, after some search around that topics I have some doubts.

As per this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14472/36463), it is stated like

> You can end up with big issues because of different extensions or when saving different config values

As per this [blog](http://severalnines.com/blog/how-cluster-magento-nginx-and-mysql-multiple-servers-high-availability), the approach was each magento instance have separate database. But I feel it seems to hard sync files and db in all three instance.

Please suggest how to achieve nginx load balance without degrade performance.

**Info:**  easy for your [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2DLa.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To archive what you want you  needs to follow a simple rule: **you application should not use local resources.**

In case of Magento it mostly about filesystem resources.

So you need:

- use redis for sessions and caches.
- use distributed fs or nfs for media folder.

Comment: Thanks for point me right direction. I completed load balancer task with two magento instance + one database with included your suggestion too  (redis session and cache + shared nfs media folder).